# How to access the ppts stored in the media folder in to views.py to perform certain operations in django

Tags: python, django, python-pptx

*i have added the code in settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

also in urls.py

```
        from django.contrib import admin
        from django.urls import path
        from django.urls import  include
        from django.conf import settings
        from django.conf.urls.static import static   
           urlpatterns = [
                path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                path('', include('cmp.urls')),
                path('', include('usr.urls')),
                path('', include('com.urls')),
                         ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

the code written in views.py is

```
        import os
        from pptx import Presentation
        from django.conf import settings
        settings.configure()
        your_media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'media/input/Bebras_Best_of_school.pptx'
        prs = Presentation(your_media_root)
        title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
        slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
        title = slide.shapes.title
        subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]
        title.text = "Hello, World!"
        subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"
        prs.save('test.pptx')
```

and the error i m getting is

```
   pptx.exc.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'media/input/Bebras_Best_of_school.pptx'
```

the file location is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK7mE.png)

i have added the ppts in the input folder of media and i want to access them in cmp folder in views.py

can you please help me*

Comment: This means Python is not finding a file by that name at that path or that the file with that name is not a PowerPoint PPTX-format file. I would check the location of the file to make sure it's looking where you expect.

Comment: Yaa sure. I have added the file location above.Kindly find the attachment